# After mvc project publish where controller save in which folder in which folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When we publish our project Which we built in MVC. Where controller and model save and in which format.

Answer (score 2):

**Your models and controllers are compiled and put in folder called bin**. If you look, you should find a DLL in that folder with the name of your project.